# Regex to add missing selectors to invalid CSS

Tags: php, css, regex, pcre

I'm trying to transform invalid CSS like this:

`{color:red}`

and make it valid like this:

`.missing_selector{color:red}`

Example CSS:

```
a {
color:black;
background-color:blue;
}

{color:red}
<!-- TEST -->

@media screen and (max-width:620px) {
/* TEST 2 */
a.test {color:blue;}
p[class="test2"] {color:green;}
}
```

My current regular expression:

`/([^a-z0-9\)\];\-_]*\{)/i`

Live test:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/eMq

Comment: Just a hint, not an answer, but maybe this library helps: https://github.com/sabberworm/PHP-CSS-Parser A solution with regex alone is rather error-prone, I suppose.

Comment: You can try [`/^\h*\K(?={)/m`](https://regex101.com/r/mC7pI5/1) and replace by `.missing_selector`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## The Solution

You need to use this:

```
/(?<=\A|\})(\s*)\{/m
```

Replace with:

```
.missing-selector {
```

The `(?<=\A|\})` makes sure that there only thing (other than whitespace) before the `{` is the start of the string or a closing `}`. (Thanks to [Casimir et Hippolyte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2255089/casimir-et-hippolyte) for pointing out the problem there.)

[Here's a **regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bQ3lB4/2).

## Why Your Attempt Failed

This

```
/([^a-z0-9\)\];\-_]*\{)/i
```

doesn't do what you think.

- `(` starts a capturing group
- `[^a-z0-9\)\];\-_]` requires a character other than `a-z`, `0-9`, `)`, `]`, `;`, `-`, or `_`
- `*` zero or more times
- `\{` requires the `{`
- `)` ends the capturing group

But it doesn't have a `^`, so it's not tied to the start of a line, nor does it validate whatever comes before the `{` (which should be only the start of the string, whitespace or a `}`). As a result, it will match everywhere you have a series of spaces or other non-alphanumeric characters (excluding `)];-_`) in your sample CSS:

[image: screenshot of regex101 demo]

[See this **regex101 demo** for a fuller explanation and example matches](https://regex101.com/r/tC6oP7/2).

Comment: Thanks @EdCottrell, this does exactly what I need it to. I really appreciate the explanation as well.